# Install symfony2 bundle without composer

Tags: symfony, installation, bundle

I had like to install a bundle in Symfony : FOSUserBundle

All search end up using composer.

I'm working in a company behind a proxy with authentication.

I can't write down my password in a config file as it would be on a shared files server.

So, i'd like to install a Bundle without using composer. What is the best way to achieve that task ?

Thank you for reading my poor english and spending time answering me.

FoW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy the same project on your local machine, install all vendors using composer, and when it is set and done - upload all project files to the shared file server.

Comment: Thank you, I was cioming to this option too.

Comment: I still don't understand why SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.yourdomain.com:8080 && php composer.phar install doesn't work (I used my own username/pw/proxy_url and port of course) still have : 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: Have you tried also setting lowercase `http_proxy`? 
if you end up "copying files from local machine" method, make sure to adjust your symfony/icu version in composer.json according to (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html), _ICU and Deployment Problems_ , or you might run into some problems.

Comment: I've just tried with a lowercase http_proxy i have the same answer. Your point about symfony.icu is very precioux thank you.

Comment: I've just found what was the problem : Domain_name\user instead of user

Comment: Ok domain name issue check. Now, I have a "failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:" I'm on WinXp i set http_proxy as a environment variable and restarted my computer.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you have to store your password in a config file. If you working behind a proxy, you have to type your password only in installation. If you don't want to use composer you have to download the bundle and add it to AppKernel.php. but the problem is that if your bundle depend of other library you will have some noise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I also tried to put user/pw on command line but it doesn't work, i don't know why but the proxy here is really tricky.

If I download the bundle, where do I have to put it ? In vendor ?

I did that and I add new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(), in appKernel.php but I have the following error :
Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found

What am I doing wrong ?